# Angular File Input selected file is not showing

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-file-input

Actually I'm trying to learn angular stuff here.

The first thing i want to do is do some simple file upload.

I already have my Web API and i already have a simple file select but the problem is it's not showing the browsed file

Here is the screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdWti.png)

In the screenshot. I already browse a file. But the problem is it's now showing the selected file. But when i move the mouse over my choose file input. The filename will popup like a toolkit. But the name is not set in the file input. How can i do that?

And below is the HTML code i'm using

```
<div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01"
          aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you create a demo on stackblitz.com ? I do not see code for browse button and the  `choose file` seems to be a `placeholder`. If you can show a demo code on above link, then I can try to fix that. In my case, I used another `input type="text" readonly` field which was showing the selected file. I'll try to make those changes in your code accordinly. Make sure you do `@shashank` while replying to comment.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can read files selected by using change event on the input.

For example, 
In component template -

```
<input (change)="onFileChange($event)" type="file" id="inputGroupFile01">
```

and in the class -

```
  files: any[];

  onFileChange(event){
    this.files = event.target.files;
    // here you can take more action like reading content, etc
  }
```

the 'files' is an array of selected files which gives information you may use for your task, like name, size, type, last modified, etc.

for more information please refer following - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

I hope this would be useful.